# What happens if my udp package is larger than mtu

Tags: udp, mtu

What would happen if my udp package is larger than mtu? Say my package is 512 bytes, after encapsulated, the package is 572 bytes. In transporting, some intermediate node fix it mtu size to 512 bytes, so what happens? Does my package simply being discarded?

In general, what is the best size of a udp package which fits for most of network situation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The package will still be sent, however the network interface layer (i.e. ethernet) will use multiple network transmissions to send it. You are still limited in size however by the maximum size for a UDP datagram (65535) as enforced by UDP/IP. See [MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) and [UDP Packets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Packet_structure) on Wikipedia for more info.

Comment: So what do I recieved? One single package or fragmented packages?

Comment: You (at the software layer, in user space) receive a single datagram. Your network card receives the transmission in multiple fragments but this is transparent to you.

Comment: So there's still a risk that some pieces of fragmented packages got lost, and the actual package I got is wrong, right?

Comment: No, if any of the fragments are lost, the entire UDP datagram is dropped. You either get the entire datagram or nothing.

Comment: Thanks very much for answering.